# How to pass SQLite database data to activity and add value too that data?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-intent

I want to add element to a data in database. I'm using clickable listView to go to another activity using intent. I already can go to another activity but i can't get the data, it's null. Also i want to add some value to that data and i'm still don't find the way to do it.

This is my XML for intent activity

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ap"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ap_x"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="x (decimal)"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLength="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ap_y"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="y (decimal)"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLength="10" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Calibrate" />


</LinearLayout>
```

This is part of my listview class

```
List<ScanResult> results;
    ListView wifisList;
    protected CharSequence[] options;
    protected boolean[] selections;
    ArrayAdapter<Router> arrayAdapter;
    ArrayList<Router> wifis;
    String building;
    Button save;
    public final static String ID="com.example.indoorpositioning._SSID";

    DatabaseHelper db;

    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        addWifi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_add);
        wifi = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        addWifi.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickHandler());
        save=(Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

        wifisList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.friendly_wifis);

        Intent intent=getIntent();

        building = intent.getStringExtra("BUILDING_NAME");
        wifis=db.getFriendlyWifis(building);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Router>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, wifis);
        // Set The Adapter
        wifisList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(db.addFriendlyWifis(building,wifis))
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Saved :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();

                }




            }
        });

        wifisList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent appInfo = new Intent(FriendlyWifis.this, ApKoor.class);
                appInfo.putExtra("SSID", String.valueOf(id));
                startActivity(appInfo);
            }
        });
```

This is my DB class

```
private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.indoorpositioning/databases/";
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "u236344269_indor.db";
    public static final String AP_TABLE = "access_points";
    public static final String READINGS_TABLE = "readings";
    public static final String AP_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE 'access_points' "
            + "('building_id' TEXT NOT NULL ,'ssid' TEXT NOT NULL,'mac_id' TEXT NOT NULL )";
    public static final String READINGS_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE 'readings' ('building_id' TEXT NOT NULL , "
            + "'position_id' TEXT NOT NULL , 'x' FLOAT NOT NULL, 'y' FLOAT NOT NULL, "
            + " 'ssid' TEXT NOT NULL , 'mac_id' TEXT NOT NULL , 'rssi' INTEGER NOT NULL )";
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public ArrayList<Router> getFriendlyWifis(String building_id) {
        ArrayList<Router> result = new ArrayList<Router>();
        System.out.println(building_id);
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select ssid,mac_id from " + AP_TABLE
                + " where building_id=?", new String[] { building_id });
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
            result.add(new Router(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1)));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        return result;

    }
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public boolean addFriendlyWifis(String building_id, ArrayList<Router> wifis) {
        deleteFriendlyWifis(building_id);
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        for (int i = 0; i < wifis.size(); i++) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("building_id", building_id);
            cv.put("ssid", wifis.get(i).getSSID());
            cv.put("mac_id", wifis.get(i).getBSSID());
            db.insert(AP_TABLE, null, cv);
        }
        System.out.println("Adding done");
        return true;
    }
```

And this is my intent activity

```
    String passedVar = null;
    private TextView passedView = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ap_koor);

        passedVar = getIntent().getStringExtra(FriendlyWifis.ID);
        passedView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ap);
        passedView.setText("AP="+passedVar);
    }
```

Also the BUILDING_PATH is saying it never used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  `wifisList.setOnItemClickListener`,your passing the intent name `SSID`.

```
 Intent appInfo = new Intent(FriendlyWifis.this, ApKoor.class);
 appInfo.putExtra("SSID", String.valueOf(id));
```

But in receive intent activity,you intent with the wrong name.

```
passedVar = getIntent().getStringExtra(FriendlyWifis.ID);
```

You should replace this line

```
public final static String ID="com.example.indoorpositioning._SSID";
```

to `SSID`.

```
public final static String ID="SSID";
```

Comment: it works, but i want to get the SSID name. it show only the index. and how to add element to that data from the intent activity?

Comment: because you are passing `String.valueOf(id)`.